# Call out to secondary audience

Tags: information-architecture, audience

I'm working on a website/online store where the primary audience is retail consumers. For a secondary audience, in this case, health care professionals, we want to send them to a separate site targeted towards their needs. From a UX standpoint, what is the best way to address this?

I'm envisioning some kind of a drawer in the header with the words, "Health Care Professional?" that when clicked, provides information about the other site with a link to go there.

Anyone have good examples of this? Or a better approach?

Comment: Do you have a mockup or wireframe of what you envision? I don't understand what you mean by "drawer in the header"

Answer (score 1):

What you are referring to is called **Segmentation**:

> Market segmentation is a marketing term that refers to aggregating prospective buyers into groups or segments with common needs and who respond similarly to a marketing action. Market segmentation enables companies to target different categories of consumers who perceive the full value of certain products and services differently from one another.

<sub>*Source [investopedi.com](https://www.investopedia.com/terms/m/marketsegmentation.asp)*</sub>

One of the most direct ways to propose segmentation by audience on a website or e-commerce is through CTA on a **landing page**:

[image]

<sub>*Source [wordstream.com/](https://www.wordstream.com/blog/ws/2010/03/08/segment-landing-pages)*</sub>

There is a lot of information on the internet about [landing page segmentation](https://filipkonecny.com/2023/04/15/landing-page-segmentation/).

Comment: That puts all 3 user types at the same level which isn't at all what I want. 95% of visitors will be consumers. But I still need to speak to the other 5%.